# Difference between Gauss-Bonnet Theorem's proof on surface.

Tags: differential-geometry

I saw there are two different proofs of Gauss-Bonnet Theorem on surfaces, where one is by do Carmo, where he do it by first proving the local Gauss-Bonnet Theorem (geodesic triangle) and then conclude it with the global one. Another proof of Gauss-Bonnet Theorem is they used integration on forms, whereby they used generalized Stoke's theorem to prove global Gauss-Bonnet Theorem.

Is the Gauss-Bonnet Theorem proved using both of these methods the same theorem? Are there any differences?

Comment: The differential forms approach proves the local version quite nicely, as well. It is the superior approach.

Comment: @TedShifrin
So you are saying both methods prove the same theorem (same condition, same result) right?

Comment: Yes, but the proof with forms gets the global result directly, as you pointed out, but the local coordinates proof cannot. The forms approach, of course, generalizes to higher dimensions (Chern's great theorem).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the clarification!